# Adding button in pdf made using pdf package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I am using the [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package in flutter for generating pdf from the app. I need to add a clickable kind of thing(hyperlink, button) in pdf but the package doesn't provide any widget for that purpose. Also, the basic flutter widgets couldn't be used for generating the pdf files(restricted by the package). Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved now, the pdf package provides the UrlLink for the purpose of opening a link when tapped on the page.

[This](https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/UrlLink-class.html) is the short documentation for the same.

I did it like this-

```
pw.UrlLink(destination: imageUrl, child: pw.Text('LINK', style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: size)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Stack` widget to put any widget above the pdf ?

Comment: I am generating the pdf and saving it to the device, I want that button in the generated pdf file.